# Setting different Cell-Formats in a Matlab uitable

Tags: matlab, properties, formatting, matlab-uitable

I am looking for a way to handle different type of data in one column of a Matlab `uitable`.

Usually `uitable` is used to set whole columns to the same data type, such as `logical` (gives a checkboxes), `char` (gives left-aligned text), `numeric` (gives right-aligned number) or a 1xn-cell-array (gives pop-up menus with different choices).

It is set using the `columnformat` property of `uitable`, e.g.

```
columnformat = {'numeric', 'logical', {'Fixed' 'Adjustable'}}; % 3 columns
```

You can find an example [at matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/uitable.html).

I am looking for a way to set the format for single cells to realize something like this:

[image: different cell formats in a uitable]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matlab's uitable is a crippled version of an underlying JIDE table.
It is possible to get to the underlying java (see [findjobj](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14317-findjobj-find-java-handles-of-matlab-graphic-objects) in file exchange), but that requires a lot of work.  Yair Altman's undocumented matlab site is a good starting place for understanding the java side of matlab.

It sounds like you want something like a property editor, as opposed to a generic UI table -- i.e. properties listed in first column, property value editable in second column.  There are a few "off the shelf" versions in the file exchange, which use JIDE:

See  [propertiesgui](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38864-propertiesgui-display-properties-in-an-editable-context-aware-table), or [property-grid](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28732-property-grid-using-jide-implementation) for mostly functional examples.  The second example is easier to use -- you simply provide a class or struct, and it creates the proper field entry format.  The first one offers more choices -- like color boxes, drop downs, etc, but requires you to be more involved in specifying how things behave.

Comment: Fyi: I have used `propertiesGUI`. Note, that it is not obvious how to handle it as a not standalone. After all I suggest to add a `uipanel` to your gui; embed `propertiesGUI` via `propertiesGUI(handles.myUiPanel, myProperties)` (add this in openingFunction); access data via `myProperties = getappdata(handles.myUiPanel,'mirror')`

Comment: VERY IMPORTANT: before replacing old propertiesGUIs by `propertiesGUI(handles.myUiPanel,myProperties)` you have to delete the old GUI element via `hPropsPane = findall(0,'Tag','hpropertiesGUI'); if ~isempty(hPropsPane),      delete(hPropsPane(1)); end` Multiple GUI handles in one panel are not supported.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but in the end it worked by giving the (numeric) cell an (char) initial value. When changing the char value from the UI the format of the cell remained char, although the rest of the column was numeric.